# Count Cols in Pivot Table VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

All,

I have a pivot which varys in column width therefore I am trying to count the amount of columns in a pivot, I have the below code which errors on the line highlighted

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
pt.ColumnRange.Count **ERROR**
```

Please can someone advise how to best count cols in a pivot table.

Comment: https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/ has a good overview of how to reference ranges in pivot tables: pick the area you want and then use `.Columns.Count` to give you the number of columns.

Comment: Did you put something like `Debug.Print pt.ColumnRange.Count` or was it just `pt.ColumnRange.Count`?  On it's own it will return `Invalid Use of Property`  It returns a number so you need to do something with it - assign it to a variable, display it in a message box, etc.  Saying that though, I'm not sure what it counts - my test had 3 columns and it returned the value 8 which equals the total number of rows in my data including headers, but pretty sure it's not that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try getting the number of columns with `pt.TableRange2.Columns.Count`

**Code**

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim NumofCols As Long

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
NumofCols = pt.TableRange2.Columns.Count
```

If all you want to do is to make their column width fit, use the line below:

```
pt.TableRange2.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Comment: Just beat me to it.  The count includes the Total column which could be a pain.